# How to check which user has stopped the dataflow pipeline in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a Data flow pipeline running on GCP which reads the messages from pub/sub and writes to GCS bucket.My dataflow pipeline status is **cancelled** by some user and I want to know who that user is ?

Comment: Have you check the logs? Try to filter using the Pipeline ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can view all Step Logs for a pipeline step in Stackdriver Logging by clicking the Stackdriver link on the right side of the logs pane.

Here is a summary of the different log types available for viewing from the Monitoring→Logs page:

- **job-message** logs contain job-level messages that various components of Cloud Dataflow generate. Examples include the
  autoscaling configuration, when workers start up or shut down,
  progress on the job step, and job errors. Worker-level errors that
  originate from crashing user code and that are present in worker logs
  also propagate up to the job-message logs.
- **worker** logs are produced by Cloud Dataflow workers. Workers do most of the pipeline work (for example, applying your ParDos to
  data). Worker logs contain messages logged by your code and Cloud
  Dataflow.
- **worker-startup** logs are present on most Cloud Dataflow jobs and can capture messages related to the startup process. The startup
  process includes downloading a job's jars from Cloud Storage, then
  starting the workers. If there is a problem starting workers, these
  logs are a good place to look.
- **shuffler** logs contain messages from workers that consolidate the results of parallel pipeline operations.
- **docker** and k**ubelet** logs contain messages related to these public technologies, which are used on Cloud Dataflow workers.

As mentioned in previous comment you should filter by Pipeline ID, the actor of the task will be in the AuthenticationEmail entry.